# How to Specify a Viewport on Android Camera API

Tags: android, camera, zooming, pan

1) The Camera previews at 1920 x 1080

2) I record at 960 x 540

3) I want to be able to specify what portion of the 1920 x 1080 preview should be saved into the video and change this on-the-fly.

In effect this would give me the ability to do digital zooming as well as digital panning of the Camera. What APIs, code-samples could help me out here?

I've looked at the Camera2 API and samples. Looks like you can only set one viewport for the device, not per output.

Comment: Just because you don't know the answer is no reason to downvote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement this zooming yourself; the camera API produces the same field of view on all of its outputs, regardless of the resolution of each output (though it does crop different aspect ratios differently, to avoid stretching).  The camera2 SCALER_CROP_REGION (used for digital zoom) will zoom/pan all outputs equally.

The simplest way to do this is probably to send the 1080p output to the GPU, and from the GPU, render to the screen with the full FOV, and render to a media recorder with just the region of the image you want to record.
It's not terribly straightforward, since you'll need to write quite a bit of OpenGL code to accomplish this.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks.